# How to change icon of custom menu?

Tags: magento2, module, favicons, custom-menu, icon

I try to change the icon on my custom menu, and I follow steps on Ibnab post, but doesn't function for me.
I looked on every post in this page , but I don't know if all steps work on my Magento 2.3

> I follow this step, make a module, and inject the custom menu , with CSS file , I see this method worked but don't put the font icon in format SVG

I need help with another steps, or guide for change the icon in my custom menu.